# How to Find text strings and Return the Sum of Cells Below strings In Excel

Tags: excel, function

I have a dataset where I like excel to count the the sum of every cell that is marked as "A" in the cell above.

So that in this dataset I would get 63 when I type in the formula.

I tried to use MATCH and INDEX functions but at very best they can recognize the "A" and give me result of 30, but I cannot manage to make it count through the whole dataset.

Thanks for help guys.

[image: Dataset]

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIF():

```
=SUMIF(B2:C8,"A",B3:C9)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution. I was trying to over complicate this in my head using match and offset.